# Angular - Google analytics custom event

Tags: angular, google-analytics

Is it possible to send custom events like below to google analytics from angular project

```
ga('send', 'event', {
eventCategory: eventCategory,
eventLabel: eventLabel,
eventAction: eventAction,
eventValue: eventValue,
customeventkey1: value,
customeventkey2: value,
..........
```

});

Comment: Yes, it's same way like non angular project

Comment: @Sandeep , You mean to say we can send custom event like above.?

Comment: you can send like ga('event', 'event', 'Video', 'cats.mp4');

Answer (score -1):

Google analytics doesn't support the format you are trying to use. Inorder to pass more information with an event, you have to configure custom dimension(string) or metric(number).

```
ga('send', 'event', category, action, label, {
  'dimension1': 'bob', // some info
  'metric1': 10 // other info
});
```

For more information: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

For practical purposes, these type of deep integrations are hard to maitain and if the systems are dynamically changing, you may miss some changes to be mapped. Platforms like [Fibotalk](https://fibotalk.com) are highly useful as they keep tracking major events automatically and retrospective analysis can be done.

Disclaimer: I am part of product engineering team at [Fibotalk](https://fibotalk.com).